# Random numbers in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, random

Hey this is my first program but i dont know how to set the random number right          i want to get a number betwen 1 and 100

```
set /a number=%random% %%100 +1
:start
set number=%random%
if %v1% EQU %number% color 0a&&echo&&goto end
if %v1% LSS %number% &&goto start
if %v1% GTR %number% &&goto start
:end
```

Comment: `set /a number=%random% %%100 +1` pretty much should generate a random number between 1 and 100.What exactly is the problem?

Comment: what is `v1` set to? why are you setting `%number%` twice?

Comment: the v1 is for the things i tip in in the cmd

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code, you are overwriting the computed variable `number` by the line `set number=%random%`.
If you want to display the result, you should replace that line by `set number` or `echo %number%`.

If you want to retrieve a new random number for each comparison of `%number%` and `%v1%` (wherever the latter comes from), you need to move `:start` one line up.

---

`%RANDOM%` expands to an integer number from `0` to `32767`. The rest is maths:

```
set /a number=(%random%*100)/32768+1
```

- minimum value: `%random%` equals `0`, so `%number%` is `1`;
- maximum value: `%random%` equals `32767`, so `%number%` is `100`;

The returned values in `%number%` are almost equally distributed.

---

In the line `if %v1% EQU %number% color 0a&&echo&&goto end`, you should replace all the `&&` by `&`, because `&&` is a conditional command separator which executes a subsequent command only if the preceding one succeeds, but here I suppose this is not the intention.

---

You could omit the `if %v1% LSS [...]` and `if %v1% GTR [...]` lines and 
replace them by a single `goto start` command... anyway, there is a syntax error in both lines -- remove the `&&`.

There is a sole `echo` in that line which will return `Echo is {on|off}.`, but I guess you want to echo some thing else.
If it is the current random number you want to display, write `echo %number%` instead.

Comment: but `%random% %% 100 +1 ` also gives number between 1 and 100 - remainder is always between 0 and 99 and the `+1` shifts the result to 1-100.

Comment: Yes, that's true, @npocmaka, but 1-68 appear more probably than 69-100 using the modulus... of course also for my implementation, not all numbers are equiprobable, but the probabilities are distributed in a balanced manner over the total range...

Comment: ther is also a message which come so i cant replace those

Comment: Yes, the modulus method is theoretically infinitesimally skewed in favor of numbers <= 68, whereas your method is theoretically evenly distributed. But I believe the non-randomness of %random% overwhelms the skew. I ran both methods 100,000 times and observed these probabilities: Modulus (1-68)=1.00089%, (69-100)=0.99811%. Your method (1-68)=1.00075%, (69-100)=0.99827%. Ideally each digit should have a 1.00000% chance of hitting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for analysing, @dbenham! Assuming that `%RANDOM%` is equally distributed, the problem of my method is that some numbers are not as probable as others, caused by down-rounding, but those are spread over the range (0-100) equally (symmatrically); actually every multiple of `32768/100` for `%RANDOM%` causes `%NUMBER%` to increase by 1; in other words, every `3.125`th `%NUMBER%` is less probable than the others (`3.125=100/(100-32768%100)`, `%` is mod.); e. g., 328 values `%RANDOM%=656...983` result in `%NUMBER%=3`, but only 327 values `%RANDOM%=984...1310` result in `%NUMBER%=4`;...

Comment: @dbenham, finally I found the "most perfect" algorithm: `%RANDOM%/(32768/100)+1`; since this could also return `101` you need to repeat computation in case; however, the great advantage is every individual `%NUMBER%` is returned by exactly 327 values of `%RANDOM%`; see also [this chart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LUkNF.png) which compares 3 algorithms (relying on 100'000'000 samples); the 3rd plot is the latest formula, the 4th one is a scaled version of the 3rd because of the lower average frequency as potential values `%NUMBER%=101` are discarded (68 values of `%RANDOM%` result in that value);

Answer (score -1):

```
set /a number=(%random%*100)/32768+1
:start
set %random%
if %v1% EQU %number% color 0a&&echo&&goto end
if %v1% LSS %number% &&goto start
if %v1% GTR %number% &&goto start
:end
```

ihave done it like this now and it work.
my mistake was that i wrote down
    set number=%random%
but now if i start the program ther stands something like this variabl "4875" is not definated.
pls help me another time

Comment: firstly, there is a `set` command missing at the beginning of the first line of code; secondly, what do you want the line `set %random%` to do? do you want to display the number? if so, write `set number` instead...

Comment: its a smal quizz whre you have to find the right number betwen 1 and 100. so i dont want to show the number. but if you have an idear how to count the atemps i need will be cool.

Comment: `set /a counter=0` before `:start`, then state `set /a counter+=1` within the `:start` section that is looped;